# Should we remind use to accept an answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we respond at 0% accept rate ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79762/should-we-respond-at-0-accept-rate)

Is it a good idea to keep reminding users to check and accept an answer, specially when you  put the time and effort to provide an answer, then a week goes by with no accept to any of the working answers.