# Should you remind the author of a question to accept an answer

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we respond at 0% accept rate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79762/should-we-respond-at-0-accept-rate)
>   [Should we remind use to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79769/should-we-remind-use-to-accept-an-answer)

Assuming you come across a question and there is an answer with a few votes. You are positive that this is the right answer so you vote the answer one up.

Is it okay to tell the author to consider accepting one of the answers?

Comment: Am I down-voted, because of the quality of the question, or because you disagree with the statement in my question?

Comment: On meta its usually because of people not agreeing with you.  I see nothing wrong with the quality of your question.  Other than the possible duplicates.

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine. People probably downvote to express that they don't think one should tell the author to consider accepting one of the answers. See  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Neither of the cited duplicates are valid duplicates of this question. Furthermore, the second cited duplicate, which is very close but not the same as this, was also closed as a duplicate to a very different question (that being the first cited here).

Comment: In many cases these accept comments are effective, but are left behind as noise long after the question has an accepted answer. Can we make it a point of good etiquette that those who make these comments go back and check/delete some time later?

Comment: @martinclayton I agree this would make sense, since the comment is not of any value once the question is accepted. Maybe you should post this suggestion as a question.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it okay to tell the author to consider accepting one of the answers?

Except in the case of completely new users who may not know the system ([as pointed out by Lix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121918/138112)): No. Accept nagging is terribly annoying. The author may not have had the time to test the answers yet - and even if they did: accepting an answer is not mandatory.

Giving a cool answer, but never having it accepted, is one of the risks of being active on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't consider leaving one comment as "nagging". When done politely and informatively, I don't see much wrong.

Comment: @Matt I agree with you if it's a new user who may simply not know the feature (See Lix's answer). But other than that, to me, it's always nagging. Everyone serious about using the sites will give accept marks *eventually* when they see their accept rate is low.

Comment: @Pekka I'm not sure that I agree. I've seen a lot of users with dozens of questions who had no idea what the accept rate was.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that in the case of a new user and possibly his first question it is acceptable to politely remark about the "accept an answer" feature as many new users confuse the voting feature as the acknowledgement or a "this was helpful".

I usually also include a link to : [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)

Comment: +1 always give a link, if you do this, else it is just plain nagging without helping

Comment: This (the case of new users) is an important point.