# Improve the indication to askers that they can accept answers to questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, new-users, unanswered-questions

I'm a new user, I've only been around for two days. I just found out that I could [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), because I was curious about those green tick things. At first, I did not know what they were. Now I know, but it was not immediately apparent to me.

I think that providing a little more information when questions are asked would go a long way towards solving [the problems of questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79762/157489).

I would add a little notice below the "Notify [email] daily of any new answers" message to say that I can come back and click the tick to accept an answer. For example,

> The tick lets you choose / accept the answer that was most helpful.

Comment: Given the upvotes, it seems people agree. But like The Renamed Exception explained, it's actually [in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Do the upvoters really want things to be more explicit?

Comment: @Arjan: Hard to say. I have found that upvotes on questions on meta sometimes still do mean "You raise a good point" not necessarily "I agree". Also I think this question had 3 upvotes before I answered. I personally didn't vote at all... I would have upvoted because it was a new user asking a good question but downvoted because I disagreed, so I didn't vote either way.

Comment: I still feel that it could be just a little more obvious, like changing the back ground color of the ticks to hi-light them. They can be a little difficult to see. My initial point is that it was not entirely obvious what they were the for and what they did.

Comment: I see there is a little message now that pops up when I up vote on some items. I am satisfied. Thanks for listening.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort put into providing solutions and fixing up this little issue. The notices, and bigger tick have made a difference in my life.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you hover over the **✔** mark/icon, a tooltip pops up:

[image: tooltip]

> Click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle

If you didn't click the accept button but instead upvoted, you would get a little box that says

> **don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark**

(The system stops showing this reminder after a certain rep threshold.)

Also, you'd see a lot of other questions on the site having big green checkmarks, so I think that's another clue you could accept answers.

It's also mentioned in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

> ### What should I do when someone answers my question?
>
> Decide if the answer is helpful, and then...
>
> - **Vote on it** (if you have earned the appropriate voting privilege). [Vote up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers that are helpful and well-researched, and [vote down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) answers that are not. Other users will also vote on answers to your question.
> - **Accept it**. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
>
> **[To accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):**
>
> - Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
> - To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
> - You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

Because all these things exist, I have always thought that the additional clarification you ask for isn't needed... I've answered meta questions stating this before. I used to be very steadfast in my position... however you as a new user bringing it up makes me rethink my position... I have always seen *longer term* users complaining that new users didn't know how to accept, and thought they were wrong. Now that I see a *new* user saying "I didn't know how to accept an answer", I think that maybe I have been wrong.

On the other hand... you *did* figure it out on your own, without the need for additional help :-)

Comment: @Josh, found a screenshot here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers/69777#69777 :)