# Notify users to select answer after few days have passed since receiving answer to first question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

<strike>For some reason it's not there, so moderator and other active users have to nag newcomers to do that, unless it's a rare case of the newcomer figuring it out by him/herself.</strike>

And there should be some sort of notification to tell the newcomer that you can select an answer to mark the thread resolved after a few days has passed since` receiving an answer to the user's first question.

Comment: There already are notifications (see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder) for instance, or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79780/improve-the-indication-to-askers-that-they-can-accept-answers-to-questions))

Comment: @Mat, I wouldn't count on either of those. For one, discovery and clicking of the arrows is a separate challenge by itself, just not as important. As for the second one, unless the users are very inquisitive, nobody would hover on the check box and wait for a tooltip to appear.

Comment: If you don't hover over stuff in the stack exchange sites, you're missing out on a whole lot of information. There's tooltips everywhere.

Comment: @Mat Doesn't mean users will simply figure there's a trove of knowledge hidden in tooltips.

Comment: I know, but the FAQ pictures are full of them too. If users don't read the FAQ, don't look around the site, don't read the notifications already presented to them, adding one more won't help much.

Comment: @Mat There's a difference between looking for information, and having the information presented to you on a silver platter (or slapped into your face, whichever you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

It's right where you'd expect it, in the section [How do I ask questions here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the **accepted answer** by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.
>
> [image]
>
> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you *don’t* do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: Ah, so there's more to it then just the main FAQ page...

Comment: Well, I'll remove that part, and focus on the notification suggestion.

Comment: What I quoted from *is* the main FAQ page, linked as “faq” in the top bar of every site.

Comment: What I mean is that you need to click and go to some other page for the info in question.

Comment: @Oxwivi No, it's the same FAQ page. You do need to click to expand the section though (which explains why you won't find “accept” in a search if you haven't clicked on the “expand” link for that section or an “expand all” link). If you think it's a bad idea to need to click to expand sections (I'm unconvinced myself), make *that* your feature request.