# Hint to accept answer for newbies

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remind new users to choose some answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers)
>   [Improve the indication to askers that they can accept answers to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79780/improve-the-indication-to-askers-that-they-can-accept-answers-to-questions/79793#79793)

I have answered quite a few questions from new users on stackoverflow. I quite often get "thanks, that worked" comments, but no accept of my answer.

I'm curious whether people here think it might be a useful addition to stackoverflow to detect this type of situation and hint at the user to accept.

I think it could be conditioned on whether there has only been one answer and the user who asked the question upvotes (or possibly even if they haven't and enough other users have, let's say 2 or more)

Comment: New users should be reading the [faq]. There's a link to it when asking a question, and up the top of the page before you join. Also, it shows an outline of a check-mark and the user can hover over it to see an informative tooltip. We already telegraph this in enough ways, imo.

Comment: I actually agree that in theory something should be done, but I'm not sure an intelligent solution is really feasible.  Though I certainly disagree with the downvotes on this question.

Comment: Note that there is already a hint which appears when the OP up votes an answer, suggesting that they might want to mark it as accepted.

Comment: thanks @hammar that was all i wanted to hear, sounds like enough to me. it just seems a bit rude when i take the time to provide a (correct) answer and it doesn't get accepted.

Comment: @hammar When they upvote. Most new users don't (up)vote.