# I find myself not answering questions, is this good?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we respond at 0% accept rate ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79762/should-we-respond-at-0-accept-rate)

I find myself every day **not answering** the basic questions when a User has less than **10 reps** or less than **50% accept rate** ...

Should I change the way I see the community or I should left this for new comers to answer and move on?

Comment: *Why*, exactly, do you find yourself not answering such questions?

Comment: You were a newbie once too, you know.  If you know the answer, provide it.

Comment: It's up to you, really. If you don't want to answer some questions, don't. There's plenty to go around.

Comment: I said, **I find my self**, so I'm not doing it on propose! It's kind'a I just answer questions and hope for high reps... :o( maybe I'm just felling blue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will say it depends your own feelings. But as said in the podcast by Skeet I guess, it's good to answer question with the same effort as the OP does ask his question.

So big question, with lot of details deserves good answer. Poor question does not.
I think accept rate may be an indicator of poor answer in a way (new user asking only question) but not only. 
Less than 10 reputation does not mean bad user as well, but new user. So you may find unexpecting question coming from them: could be bad (very bad) or very good.

So I will say look at the question. Does it sound clear, interesting and not just `gimme teh codez` like? if yes go on. It's up to you.

Comment: plenty of `gimme teh codez` answers in SO :-/ I just bypass those, even if I know the answer... It's just `rude` I think.

Answer (score 5):

Why ignore such users? Some of them are genuinely trying to figure things out. True, *send me teh codez* questions are annoying; the best way to deal with them is to simply not give them the code, instead offering them hints on how to solve the problem. This way they'll have a starting point and, if they're really interested, will solve their own problem while learning something new in the process.

Comment: I think the *best* thing to do with the true `send-me-teh-codez` "questions" is to **close** them. Of course, if you happen across one that you think can be modified into a real question, then please edit it to make it so along with providing an answer.