# Is it appropriate to finish an answer with a friendly reminder about marking an answer as accepted?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

Various questions (issues) seem to exist about users who forget to mark "an" answer as the accepted answer. Maybe adding a friendly reminder near the end of an answer would help to address this issue. Eg with something like so:

---

PS: If this answers your question, then please mark it like so (using the checkmark below the vote up/vote down icons next to this answer). Doing so you will comply with what this site expects you to do, and you will reward the user that actually answered your question (something many users seem to forget, which is why I mention it here).

---

**My Question(s)**:

- is adding such reminder "appropriate", i.e. that it does not violate any rules I'm not aware of yet?
- If it is appropriate, what would be a good template to be used, to enhance my first draft version of what I suggested above?
- Also, if these about 4 lines would be perceived as too long, how about just adding a link to some kind of template for it, With a title like "if this answers your question, then please do not forget to mark it as such".

Comment: See also: [Informing new users of how to accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135493/21960)

Comment: See also: [Is it bad form to prompt new questioners to formally accept your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12543/21960)

Comment: @AlE. thank you for the link (in your 1st comment), Just looking at the title, it seems to me that this is not a duplicate, or is it you think? The 2nd link title seems close. Give me some time to go find out. FYI:  both links didn't show up in my couple of searches I performed before asking the question.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related.

Comment: I looked at both links, indeed "related" I think, but close. The "So was it crass of me to prod the guy ..." needs more then basic English knowledge to understand it though ... crass ? prod? I know, I'm not allowed to argue about "I'm not native English". Note to myself: add both links in my OP. It's late over here now, will do so later on. Feel free to edit yourself of course ... My bookmarks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135493/21960 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12543/21960

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not appropriate. Your answer should only be for answering the question at hand. Any other commentary about upvoting or accepting, complaining about downvotes, etc does not belong in the post.

It is generally considered "acceptable" to *remind* a user they can accept an answer if they've indicated it was helpful to them and it looks like they just don't know about the accepted mark, or forgot. That remind should only ever be posted **in the comments**. These comments are still considered noise, though, and will be swiftly deleted if flagged for moderator attention.

A simple comment like this would suffice:

> If you found this helpful, remember to mark it as accepted at the left.

If a moderator notices a pattern of a particular user continually posting these comments without reason, that user can expect to receive a message in their inbox about it, asking them to stop.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Maybe 1 more refinement of your answer here: HOW to best perform that reminder, i.e via an extra comment in that answer, or by editing the answer? Would you mind refining your 'answer' with your extra 'answer' to explain how to do such reminder (pfff, oeps, sorry!)? PS: your answer here is already close for me considering it "helpful" ...

Comment: Most comments are just a simple "If you found this helpful, remember to mark it as accepted at the left." You should never edit that into your answer, though. Only post it in the comments.

Comment: Probably last 2 questions: (a) It seems it is OK to already add that comment right after you posted your answer (you do not have to wait until the OPer ever confirms) and (b) please include your comment in your answer itself (so that we can "cleanup" our quick chatbox here and not loose, for me, that valuable info) OK? I'd be happy to suggest such edit myself but ... I'm not allowed. Can you tell why?

Comment: It is not OK to add that comment immediately after posting. It's noise and looks like begging, and I guarantee you'll receive a moderator message asking you to stop doing that if a moderator catches the pattern.

Comment: Voilà, et Merci Beaucoup @animuson ... you know what: "this was REALLY" helpfull ... But give me a few more secs to proof it hé ... And may I say "glad I asked ..."?!?!

Comment: @animuson I recently voted up an answer to one of my questions, and a box popped up with a message similar to that which you've suggested here. Is that network-wide? If so, it seems that the system is, at least in certain cases, handling this matter.  Granted, the OP has to upvote an answer in order to trigger the message, but maybe the person who posted the answer could wait a bit before adding a comment, at least until after the answer has an upvote. (Obviously the upvote didn't necessarily come from the OP, but I'm sure you know what I'm getting at.)