# What happens to dead questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

What happens if the user who asked the question has removed his account?

Like this one: [Regex to check if valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif)

Who would approve an answer to his question?

There are two possible solutions to this case:

1. Choose the top voted question.
2. The answer will be chosen by some moderator.

Comment: Is this really a feature request?

Comment: If functionality/feature does not exists - I'd like to request it :)

Comment: You can't remove your account. You have to ask for it to be removed.

Comment: @Brad: ...And the question still remains

Answer (score 1):

In the cases of ghost and deleted accounts, nobody is available to accept an answer. All answers will just sit there gathering the stray vote.

[image: oh for they will run but they will not run fast enough]

Comment: I like the image of the stray-vote gatherer. I imagine he does it when he's not catching children or charming rats

Comment: Well, sort of on your thought...

Comment: This looks like a twisted form of StackOverflow goatse... maybe you could call it votese???

Comment: That so does not look like a burlap sack.

Comment: (-1) pictures for no reason is basically spam.

Comment: @devinb, you have a weird definition for spam!

Comment: @devinb The reason is in Rich Seller's comment.

Answer (score 0):

As for automatically accepting top vote answers, see this question:

[auto-accept-unaccepted-but-correctly-answered-questions-after-some-time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/auto-accept-unaccepted-but-correctly-answered-questions-after-some-time)

My answer was:

> There are many questions that do not
>   have satisfying answers for the OP,
>   even though answers are upvoted by the
>   community. Accepting is totally up to
>   the OP, as it is a means to reward the
>   answerer. Doing this automatically
>   would actually be missleading as it
>   would look as if the OP awarded the
>   points, thinks that his problem is
>   solved, and therefore late answers
>   after some time would be discouraged.
>   The OPs accept rate would be flawed as
>   well. Would the OP be able to unaccept
>   the answer, and accept an other one?
>   Or leave it with no accepted answer to
>   start the game again?

This holds as well for the moderator accepting.