# I have 17 reputation, but where are my vote ups?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I looked in my questions, and my vote ups are not there... from where I got the 17 reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes on this question, [If a bounty question is not correctly answered, can I ask it again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47466/if-a-bounty-question-is-not-correctly-answered-can-i-ask-it-again).

That gives you 16 rep, plus the 1 bonus rep you start with.

Once you get to 1000 rep, you'll be able to click on the vote number and see the breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

[Lance has the details on what happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48920/i-have-17-reputation-but-where-are-my-vote-ups/48921#48921), but while you re working on the 1000 rep, you can go to [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146353/tom-brito), click the ["reputation" tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146353?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) and examine the per post rep breakdown therein.