# Option to extend bounties by 24 hours

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

Here is a scenario that actually happened to me...

- I asked a question
- I got less than helpful answers
- I created a bounty
- With *hardly any time left on the bounty*, someone posted an answer

Here is the problem: I didn't have time to check the answer to see if it worked before the bounty ran out.

So I propose a '24 hr. bounty extension' button. This gives the person a chance to try answers posted at the last minute.

One more thing I thought of... probably this 'bounty extension' should prevent new answers from being considered - or the process could end up repeating itself.

Comment: @Tradition: Why...?

Comment: You're always going to have some drive-by downvotes, especially on Meta... but posting a comment consisting solely of "-1" is straight-up rude.

Comment: @Pop: You said it! *(Care to upvote...?)*

Comment: @George, I already did, I just didn't mention it in the comment.

Comment: could this not be even the default behaviour? That is, the question remains featured for 7 days but the bounty can still be awarded during the next 24 hours, without having to click a button?

Comment: I want to extend the deadline from 7 to 14 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed per

[A grace period of one day to award the bounty after expiration (without remaining featured, of course)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037)

There is a 24 hour grace period at the end of every bounty.

Comment: Cool! Glad to see that feature implemented!

Answer (score 16):

It is odd that answers arriving late in the bounty aren't, practically speaking, eligible (barring an OP with vigilant, split-second timing). But I'm not sure that extending the bounty period makes sense.

What *does* make sense is that there should be a grace period after the bounty period is over to allow the author time to select the best answer. Make the entire bounty period count. Ideally, the author should not be selecting a bounty award until the entire advertised period has elapsed, anyway. ***"The contest is over, time to pick a winner."*** It would be a short period of time -- say, 24-48 hours -- after which, if the author has not selected an answer, the normal auto-accepting process kicks in ([blech](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44590/manually-accept-answer-after-bounty-has-expired-never-auto-accept/44604#44604) <grin>).

One caveat: For new answers that arrive during the grace period... You would have to notify the author that the late-arriving answer is not eligible for the bounty and, therefore, not accept-able. That's what would happen with an auto-selected bounty anyway.

Comment: I agree - in fact that's basically what I'm saying.

Comment: @George, people have complained twice now that your question is not a feature request for a grace period. They say it's because you don't use those specific words in the question, even though Robert says it in his answer and you commented about agreeing. Would you mind editing your question to clarify that? Or do I not understand your feature request?