# Auto accepting of bounty questions

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

Last week, I tried to open a bounty for a Stack Overflow question of mine. Unfortunately, there was only one answer posted, and it's not been helpful (mostly posting results to some Google search which I had obviously already done myself).

Today, I received an e-mail notification that the top-rated answer "may" be auto-accepted once the bounty expires. This confuses me, and searching here on meta hasn't really made it any clearer.

What criteria are used for auto-accepting an answer? If something does not answer the question, it should never be accepted, imo. I gave the guy an upvote for effort, but since it doesn't help me at all, it seems unjustified to award him a 250 point bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the https://stackoverflow.com/faq ? It covers bounty quite extensively.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies the "may" bit. I don't understand the design choice of never allowing the OP to accept an answer anymore. Should someone provide a useful answer after the bounty period has expired, it should be possible to accept it? There has been some discussion about that here already though, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider for a moment that *you* (and maybe others) might have caused the mechanism to fail. Giving an "A" for "effort" only obscures the grading system. Your supposed to up-vote an answer because (from the tool tip) ***"This answer is useful."*** That's what you are telling the system—answer is useful.

When the system auto-accepts a bounty, it is accepting the "most useful" answer. Reputation is a measurement of how much the system "trusts" you. That's why it takes a certain reputation to vote. When the system applies the rules of auto-accepting, it's only responding to the information *you* and other users gave it.

Comment: Generally speaking, upvoting is outside of the control of the OP. In my case I did contribute one upvote. In the end I answered my own question with a somewhat unsatisfactory answer, but at least I can update that answer eventually, rather than being stuck with a locked in accepted answer that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Thorarin - Vote for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44590/manually-accept-answer-after-bounty-has-expired-never-auto-accept/44604#44604 and it will take care of those shortcomings.