# Auto-accept for high rated answers to questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [auto accept unaccepted but correctly answered questions after some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/auto-accept-unaccepted-but-correctly-answered-questions-after-some-time)

Should there be some mechanism in place to accept the highest rated answer with a minimum of, say, 5 up votes for a question asked over a week ago with no accepted answer? My thought is that the auto-accept should NOT count as an acceptance for the questioner and should come with fewer (5 or 10) reputation points for the auto-accepted answerer.

My reasoning is that this might be a good way to encourage reputation-obsessed people to answer questions even from newbies or people who don't quite get (or choose not to adhere to) the system.

Comment: You assume there is no mechanism in place that encourages questioners to accept good answers.  There is, they stop getting views and answers when they don't.  Works fairly well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Most votes does not necessarily imply correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Having the highest number of votes does not imply a correct answer, but what about adding the ability to vote for the correct answer to be accepted?

Limititations would have to be enforced, of course.  Perhaps require 1000 rep, and 5 votes (similar to a close vote).  Only allow accept votes after a few days?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature) and a voluminous series of related duplicates.