# What to do with "unanswered" questions where OP appears to be gone and there's a good answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I'm surprised to not see another post for this.  Sometimes a user will post one question and never respond to anything.  An answer is posted that appears to be correct.  A year goes by.  The post is still "unanswered".  Should we flag them with a note to "mark answered"?  Or...?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/auto-accept-unaccepted-but-correct-answers-after-some-time), [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)

Comment: This has come up before - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts

Comment: @Rob - Sorry, usual kind of search error - I searched "unanswered", assumed everyone would use that word.

Comment: @Ed - No need to apologize, I wasn't accusing. Was just providing more data. They may not be "exact" duplicates, anyway. Just related.

Answer (score 17):

You ask:

> Should we flag them with a note to "mark answered"?

No; don't do that. Nobody except the OP can accept an answer by proxy. Not even ♦ moderators. All you will do is create noise for the moderators to ignore.

If the answer is good, upvote the answer. That will make it clear that it has a sensible answer.