# Automatically choosing answers to questions asked by runaway users

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-accept unaccepted but correct answers after some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/auto-accept-unaccepted-but-correct-answers-after-some-time)

I've done a search and I found many posts concerning users not choosing answers to their questions. The proposed solutions however seemed to concern the users which are actually using the site after that, i.e. asking more questions, etc...

How about users who register, ask one question and go away, never using the site again. Or who show some very limited interest, i.e. add a comment but then figure out the solution on their own (which perhaps is trivial, so the original question is not valid), loose interest and don't care about the question they've asked any longer.

This is a problem, because the people who put effort into answering questions don't get the rep they deserve and also the questions which have no answer chosen are misleading, so for any people who seek help they are less useful than questions with marked answers.

Perhaps there should be a system which after some time assigns the rep? Perhaps some system for automatically choosing an answer? Not sure about the best solution, but there's definitely a problem.

Example question: [Tastypie Django POST error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750242/tastypie-django-post-error)

But there are multiple such cases in the Tastypie list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tastypie

Comment: Since this is your first post on meta, I'll go ahead and mention that [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). They indicate disagreement and not necessarily the quality of the post.

Comment: @Lix Thanks :) Does that mean you'd normally downvote os is this just a heads-up ?

Comment: Accepted answers indicate correctness or helpfulness as indicated by the OP of the question. Nothing more, nothing less. Upvotes are there for all other users and are often a better indicator of answer quality, though both may reflect the same. I see no need for the proposed feature.

Comment: Please no. First similar suggestions are asked before and rejected. Second, accepting is the privilege of the question asker. The community literally votes the best answer with upvotes, but the question asker selects the answer that best solved the problem.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe the other one is similiar, but like the ones I found it seems to assume the user will be using the site, so the reminders will have some effect ?

Comment: @kgr - It's both really.  I don't agree with this suggestion, **and** wanted to give you a heads up.

Comment: @Lix - sounds good, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This is a problem, because the people who put effort into answering questions don't get the rep they deserve and also the questions which have no answer chosen are misleading*

Well, actually they do. If the answers are good the community will upvote them and they get the reps they deserve.

In general, the score indicates how good the answers are. The "accept" only indicates which one the poster found the most useful or the one he/she ended up using.

If the poster chooses to run away after getting what he needs, so be it. If the question was good then it would just enhance the site. If it was bad then it would just be closed, deleted, or simply lost in the dark corners of SO.

Comment: "dark corners"? So SO is cubic and not spherical? :P

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like this idea. The accepted answer is not the important thing. The community votes is what you want to be striving for. Getting the check mark can get you a maximum of 15 points where votes (over time) don't have limits.

In the event that there is no "accepted" answer on a post, people will usually go with the highest votes answer. Some go directly there and ignore the accepted post simply because they believe in the communities ability to rate the quality of an answer. In a perfect world the accepted answer would in any case have the most votes, but this is not always the case.

Automatically awarding reputation to someone is done in the case of a bounty. If the user offering the bounty doesn't award it 24 hours after the bounty period has ended, 50% of the original bounty will be awarded to the highest voted answer with at least 2 upvotes. In ordinary cases, low traffic tags have this problem of...well... low traffic :P The posts there don't get that much exposure so there are not many votes cast and people don't get the reputation they deserve. Not much to do about that really...