# Highlight quality answers for abandoned question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Check out [ColdFusion adding extra quotes when constructing database queries in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266586/coldfusion-adding-extra-quotes-when-constructing-database-queries-in-strings)

Our buddy "Alex", the OP, seems that have left the building. Four years ago. I don't think he'll be back to accept an answer.

A handful of the answers show a lot of thought and have utility. The gents who took the time to answer don't necessarily need the rep from an accepted answer, but marking one of the questions as "accepted" might benefit a third party looking with the same question.

- <s>Does SO have some sort of auto-accept for orphaned questions?</s>Nevermind: [Auto-accept unaccepted but correct answers after some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21043/208489)
- <s>Would a conscientious user flag either the question or the answer (besides using the upvote) as deserving of an "acceptance"?</s>Nevermind: [Allow users to mark "accepted" answer on someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26639/208489)
- SO randomly sorts answers so as not to arbitratily give first-responders up-vote advantages; can SO be amended to order by vote total for abandoned questions?

Comment: Answers, by default, are sorted by vote, equal-vote answers are ordered randomly.

Comment: Though note that by clicking the "active" or "oldest" tabs, you can change the answer ordering

Comment: There is *no* sorting option that sorts answers in totally random order.

Comment: FWIW: if we wanted to reopen the discussion about auto-awarding accepts, I think we should consider awarding the accept to the winner of a death-match melee between all the answerers.

Comment: Ah--I see now that I've been sorting by "active" tab. Nevermind...

Comment: So...do I flag this to be closed, or just delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your feature request is already implemented.

The default sorting for answers is by vote (descending). Only answers with *equal* votes are then locally listed in random order.

So a question with answers with scores 15, 10, 10 and 8 lists the answer with score 15 first, the two answers with score 10 in random order, then the answer with score 8.

There is no answer sorting order that is completely random. The 'active' and 'older' ordering simply sort on posting and last-active dates.