# Who has ownership of a Question/Answer after the account that posted it is deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts, licensing, ownership

There has been some questions surrounding post ownership after a user voluntarily deleted their account and now they have a new account on the site. In a recent meta they referenced it as their post in terms of ownership, but with the licensing plus the disassociation of the post authorship due to the account deletion this seems like a stretch.

I'm just wondering since the account was deleted, does the original poster have any claim to the ownership of this post in terms of it being undeleted? The FAQ [Who owns the content I post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post) hints at the OP not owning it anymore, but I'd like a more direct answer for this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) See the section "What happens to my content? Can I request it be deleted as well?"

Comment: @Makyen Kind of, but not directly. In this case they want a post undeleted even though it's disassociated and deleted due to low quality reasons.

Comment: If it’s such low quality it’s been deleted, it should stay deleted, and the user reminded that deleted contributions are heavily weighted towards contribution bans

Comment: The owner of a post doesn't have a right to have a post undeleted (or deleted). If the post is to be undeleted, or not, is entirely something that's a choice on the part of the site. Until they voluntarily chose to give up the additional control which the system granted them by the system understanding they were the "owner", they did have more of a say in if something was to be deleted or undeleted. They voluntarily chose to give up that additional control. See the screen captures of the dialogs shown in the process of deleting their account.

Comment: If they were talking about copyright, then yes, they still own the copyright, but have licensed it to SE under the CC BY-SA. Owning the copyright doesn't give them a right to have SE publish it (i.e. have it not be deleted).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it make sense to add an option to request ownership of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114532/282094) I agree with the previously proposed duplicate but that's an alternative. --- Whether a question or answer remains deleted is a community moderation decision, and not entirely controlled by the OP.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "owns" and "ownership". There are multiple possible interpretations of those with respect to content posted on SE & distributed by SE. The copyright owner is, usually, the author of the content (assuming they weren't employed for the purpose of creating and posting the content). What rights are retained by the copyright holder and/or granted to SE and/or everyone else is a relatively complex subject. The primary controllers of what happens with those rights are the various copyright laws, the Terms of Service, and associated documents, and the CC BY-SA license.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the account was deleted, does the original poster have any claim to the ownership of this post in terms of it being undeleted.

The content is under the CC BY-SA license ([3.0 or 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/178179)). Anyone may post or delete the content as long as they respect that license. The identity of user who posted the content shouldn't affect whether the content is deleted.

Comment: Exactly. The site still has the full ability to curate the post regardless of the person who posted it.