# Vote to mark answer as accepted on old questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users)

A lot of questions don't have an answer marked as accepted; even though they have at least one correct answer. This might be because the user is new and doesn't fully understand how SO works, or it could just be that the user is lazy.

This is why I believe that it'd be a great idea to implement a feature so users with >x reputation can vote on an answer so it'd get accepted. Perhaps this would only be allowed in questions with 2+ answers and which hasn't had any answers accepted within three monts after the answers being posted.

It could work like the flag system does; multiple flaggers (or perhaps the review system) results in an accepted answer.

Comment: Suggested and rejected multiple times. The only person who can "Accept" an answer is the original Asker.

Comment: People already can vote on answers to indicate what they think are the best ones. The answer with the most upvotes is the one the community thinks is the best one. Nothing is gained by forcing the first answer that gets 10 upvotes the be the accepted one or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

> A lot of questions doesn't have an answer marked as accepted; even though it has at least one correct answer. This might be because the user is new and doesn't fully understand how SO works, or it could just be that the user is lazy.

Or it could be that the asker hasn't yet found an answer they consider worthy of the shiny green tick. In any case, accepting an answer is completely up to the asker and it's also completely up to them *if* and *when* they'll accept.

If a question has at least one upvoted answer, then it already has an accepted answer, accepted by the community that is. That answer won't get any better just by getting a green tick, so what's the point?

Comment: Sure, that might be the case sometimes. However, you can't deny that it's quite common to see questions with CORRECT answers without any acceptation mark.

Comment: @Zar I'm not denying it's common, I'm denying it's a problem. Who cares if it has an accepted answer, if it already has a correct answer?

Comment: Lets agree to disagree. If it doesn't matter; why not remove the accepting-mechanism as a whole instead of keeping a broken one?

Comment: @Zar If you make that a feature request, I will upvote it. However you seem to be thinking that an answer getting accepted means it's correct. Certainly that might be the case some times, but not always, the green tick just tells us what one person, the asker, thinks of the answer. That might be important, but it's certainly not more important than what the community thinks.