# Show highest voted answer at top when OP has a deleted account

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, old-questions, answer-order, deleted-accounts

My highest voted answer on stackoverflow has taken me a little by surprise and it is currently this one: [Javascript global error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556743/590956)

If you visit the link, you'll notice that the OP has since been deleted.  Its too bad since with this question alone the OP would have over 350 rep, but that's not the point.  The point is:

- The question is really old (June 4, 2009)
- The OP is gone (presumably his account has been deleted),
- The answer I gave years after his asking (May 11, 2012) is far better than previous old answers given on the same day the question was asked (June 4, 2009).

I'd like mine to be appear at the top since it appears to be the most widely accepted answer.

So - my question / feature request is - **When an OP is deleted, can we have the question with the most votes shown at the top?**

Related:
[Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users)

*Note: I'm posing my question for deleted users, not inactive users.  Is this the same thing...?*

Comment: There are a *lot* of proposals here on meta for having the appected answer marked by someone other than the OP.  They have all been rejected, for largely the same reasons (regardless of the specifics of how/when the accepted answer should be picked).  Quite simply, those details don't matter.  See the other discussion of the topic for why this isn't going to happen; all of the reasons apply to your example.

Comment: What exactly would that serve, seeing as the meaning of an accepted answer is an endorsement by the question OP?

Comment: I suspect you may be overestimating the importance of having an 'accepted' answer in the first place.

Comment: I've amended the question / feature request to not mark as the accepted answer, but rather to show highest voted answers at top (ONLY when OP has been deleted)

Comment: Maybe I am overestimating accepted answers of deleted users, since I am asking this question.  But...  has anyone actually reviewed the link I posted or read the Q in full?  Seems like a lot of fast judgement is going on

Comment: @Sam And why should we invalidate the accepted flag of the OP just because they deleted their account?  Obviously the answer they accepted worked for them.  That doesn't change just because they deleted their account.  It is still conveying exactly the information it's *supposed* to convey.

Comment: @Sam It's a suggestion seen in slightly varied forms *all the time*.  People have discussed the issue in depth quite a few times before, and already formed their opinions.  They don't need to hash it out *again* to come to a conclusion.  This is perfectly appropriate behavior.

Comment: @Servy fair enough.  :)  I'm not used to meta, but I think I've been told that downvotes are different on meta than on stack.  On stack they more or less mean that your question was poorly written, a duplicate etc...  Whereas on meta it may simply mean people disagree with your proposal or thoughts on something.  Is that the case here?  I'm not trying to beat any dead horses, and I cited a separate meta article that was similar (though not the same).

Comment: @Sam That's correct. Given that this has already been discussed and rejected, majority consensus goes against your suggestion - hence the downvotes.

Comment: @Sam That's true to a point, but making a proposal that's seen over and over (where the variations aren't germane to the rejection reasons) is also reason enough to downvote.  While this isn't a duplicate in the sense of being closed, it's still a rehash of a rehash of a rehash that doesn't address the reasons all of the previous proposals were declined.  In short, it's related to a lack of research on your part in addition to disagreeing with the proposed change.

Comment: @Sam Welcome to Meta. Two things: 1) Reputation here is absolutely worthless. 2) Meta downvotes are awesome, learn to love them. Now that's out of the way, here's an upvote. I don't completely agree with your proposal, but I think the whole accepted answer concept is problematic and needs to either be drastically adjusted or completely removed.

Comment: Meta rep worthless? Abandoning accepted answers? Are you okay @Yannis ? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, an asker will accept an answer that is seemingly not as good as another, more highly voted answer.

But this doesn't matter; the purpose of accepting an answer is to indicate which answer worked for the question asker, not necessarily the most detailed or highly voted.

As far as I'm concerned this works exactly as it should, and the question asker being deleted should have no effect given that at one point, they still chose an accepted answer.

EDIT: I've read the question. Your answer is great, and were I the asker I'd probably have accepted yours. But there's no shame in not having an answer accepted, it doesn't devalue your answer in any way.

Comment: Thanks for leaving an answer.  It seems the community at large agrees with you.  Accepted answers shouldn't be taken lightly, and as others have said the accepted answer means it worked for the OP.  Thanks for indulging me.  :)

Comment: Also, I think I'm coming around to also seeing the current behavior as the correct way of handling it.